# Create directory in a selected path using Python Tkinter 2.7

Tags: python, tkinter, directory

I would like to create a class in Tkinter Python 2.7 that creates a new directory using the name introduced by the user in a field after the directory location was chosen from filedialog. 
As an example I would like something like this:

User introduces the name of the directory and the following structure should be created:

```
$HOME\a\<name_introduced_by_the_user_in_the_field>\b 

$HOME\a\<name_introduced_by_the_user_in_the_field>\c
```

I was thinking to start simple and create a simple directory, but I am getting an error.

Here is what I have tried:

```
class PageThree(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self,text="Insert the name of your project",font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        self.projectnamevar=tk.StringVar()
        projectname=tk.Entry(self,textvariable=projectnamevar)
        projectname.pack()
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Create the directory", command=self.create_dir)
        button1.pack()

    def create_dir(self):
        call(["mkdir",projectnamevar.get()])
```

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "program.py", line 118, in create_dir
    call(["mkdir",self.projectnamevar.get()])
AttributeError: PageThree instance has no attribute 'projectnamevar'
```

How can I accomplish the whole stuff?

**P.S. I am quite new to programming**

Comment: since the `projectnamevar` variables are inside the init function it kinda of became local, so define them as `self.projectnamevar` in init function and use the same way in other functions aswell

Answer (score 0):

Your Variable projectnamevar cannot be found in the class as you have not saved it as such, try it with

```
self.projectnamevar = tk.StringVar()
```

Also, you might want to use the os module instead of calling it on the system, you can use it like this

```
import os
path = "~/my/path/"
os.mkdir(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, sys
if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import messagebox
    from tkinter import filedialog
    from tkinter.ttk import *
elif sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    print ("The Script is written for Python 3.6.4 might give issues with python 2.7, let the author know")
    print ("Note Python 2.7 CSV has a empty line between each result. couldn't find a fix for that")
    from Tkinter import *
    import tkMessageBox as messagebox
    import tkFileDialog as filedialog
    from ttk import Combobox

class temp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.top = Tk()
        self.lab = Label(self.top, text='UserFiled')
        self.en = Entry(self.top, width =25)
        self.but = Button(self.top, text='Submit',command = self.chooseFolder)
        self.lab.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.en.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.but.grid(row=0, column=2)
        self.top.mainloop()
    def chooseFolder(self):
        directory = filedialog.askdirectory()
        print(directory)
        newPath = os.path.join(directory, self.en.get())
        if not os.path.exists(newPath):
            os.chdir(directory)
            os.mkdir(self.en.get())

obj = temp()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried your code, but this one just creates the new directory called like the user wants, not the whole structure that was mentioned in the question. Can you please have a look?

Comment: @Albert I am not sure how you wanna create the directory structure from the example you have demonstrated, do you wanna create a folder with user defined name at a location and further create a subdirectory?